# Fetch a list of all tables at Alias location

Tags: database, delphi

Is there anyway that upon a user selecting an alias from a combo box it polls that alias and fetches a list of all tables within that alias?

What I'm hoping I can do is return this list of tables into a TStringList and then populate another combobox with a list of all of the tables within the alias that they selected. I have the following code to populate cbox with the availiable alias':

```
lvAliasList := TStringList.Create;
try
  session.GetAliasNames(lvAliasList);
  cboxAliasSel.Items := lvAliasList;
finally
  lvAliasList.Free;
end;
```

The above is basically what I want but instead of alias' it needs to be table names. Thanks.

Comment: You can pass an alias as database name to GetTableNames, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`TDatabase.GetTableNames`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Bde.DBTables.TDatabase.GetTableNames) or [`TSession.GetTableNames`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Bde.DBTables.TSession.GetTableNames)  method.